# Can you convert this into WeakViewModel and SingletonViewModel?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using this pattern to lazy load view model and deinit it when no page is using the view model.

The problem is, the boilerplate is getting annoying. Is there a way to make it use less boilerplate? i.e. `App1FirstViewModel: WeakViewModel`

```
final class App1FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let id: UUID
    
    @Published var counter: Int
    
    init(
        id: UUID = UUID(),
        counter: Int = 0
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.counter = counter
        printIfDebug("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id)")
    }
    
    deinit {
        printIfDebug("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id)")
    }
}

extension App1FirstViewModel {
    static func shared(counter: Int = 0) -> App1FirstViewModel {
        var temp: App1FirstViewModel
        
        if _shared == nil {
            temp = App1FirstViewModel(
                counter: counter
            )
            _shared = temp
        }
        
        return _shared!
    }
    
    private static weak var _shared: App1FirstViewModel?
}
```

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already you don't need a class, just do `@State var counter = 0` and pass down as `let` for readonly or `@Binding var` for read/write. `body` is called when ever the counter changes.

Comment: Sharing a view model with a global is... a bad idea. Why not just pass it from parent-to-child like usual?

Comment: @Alexander I created 2 separate project, one that pass parent to child and one that in the global. when I make change to the view model, the parent view reinit, and child also reinit. meanwhile, when i use global, it does not reinit.